# How many excel process i can invoke using c#

Tags: excel, office-interop

I have an application (web) which suppose to open separate excel process for each session. When i try this, server opened only 20 process, is it a restriction or is their a way to open more than 20 Excel.exe process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this depends on your system resources.

However I can tell you from personal experience that Excel Interop is not a recommended solution to web applications e.g. C# ASP.NET. See here even: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0

Why else?:

1. Excel Interop uses a lot of system resources and your web application will soon run into many performance issues.
2. Excel Interop has to be installed on the server and there are also issues with the process identity. Installation and configuration is sometimes hard and differes for 32 bit and 64 bit systems.
3. Sometimes for, God knows what, reasons Excel Interop processes will not close immediately (not only if some Interop resources are unreleased). Then you will have to close these processes yourself which is a real pain.

Why not use OpenXML or even better ClosedXML? You will see your code running even 100x faster with Excel files as OpenXML/ClosedXML treats Excel files as XML files and does not create additional processes for intermediary operations.

CloseXML link: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm making the excel file interactive via web. So my calculations happens inside the excel. I have define a way to close the excel and it's working nicely only issue is i can run only 20 concurrent sessions.

Comment: Ok, understood. Are you making a corporate solution? Maybe you could host it via SharePoint (MS SharePoint has such features)? Only other option I can think of is to make a query queue - you would have to manage the amount of queries you receive to execute your Excel calculations so that they do not exceed the tested 20 processes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, As you mention queue would be the best thing. Thanks a lot for your quick response. Not sure whether its a Microsoft restriction so checking on it as well.

Comment: As I said I do not suppose it to be a strictly Excel process restriction but a general problem of resources (e.g. process, resource handles). In my case I think it was more processes - approx. 25 or more. Anyway I would appreciate the +1 if my answer was useful to u